# Scrollbar, Checkbutton and canvas in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, scrollbar

I try to open a new window where there will be a list of check box and will be scrollable.

But, my list is not scrolled.
this is my code:

```
class PageCanvas1(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        global arr
        global users
        arr = {}
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.title('Canvas')
        self.geometry('400x600')
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg='white', scrollregion=(0, 0, 400, 20000))
        canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        vbar = tk.Scrollbar(canvas, orient='vertical')
        vbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        vbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
        canvas.config(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
        canvas.create_text(5, 0, anchor='nw', text="Choose users: ")
        for i in range(1000):
            arr[i] = tk.IntVar()
            Checkbutton(canvas, text=str(i), variable=arr[i]).pack()#.grid(row=i, sticky=W)

root = Tk()
b_choose = Button(root, text='choose users', height=3, width=15, bg="turquoise", command=(lambda arr=ents: PageCanvas(root)))
```

[image: no scroll]

I can not find any answer to this specific thing, that a new window must be opened! I would be happy to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import Tkinter as tk

class PageCanvas1(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        global arr # why use global? set it as an attribute?
        global users # same as above?
        arr = {}
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.title('Canvas')
        self.geometry('400x600')
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg='white', scrollregion=(0, 0, 400, 20000))
        canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        vbar = tk.Scrollbar(canvas, orient='vertical')
        vbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        vbar.config(command=canvas.yview)
        canvas.config(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
        canvas.create_text(5, 0, anchor='nw', text="Choose users: ")
        # we need a container widget to put into the canvas
        f = tk.Frame(canvas)
        # you need to create a window into the canvas for the widget to scroll
        canvas.create_window((200, 0), window=f, anchor="n")
        for i in range(0, 1000):
            arr[i] = tk.IntVar()
            # widget must be packed into the container, not the canvas
            tk.Checkbutton(f, text=str(i), variable=arr[i]).pack()#.grid(row=i, sticky=W)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = PageCanvas1(None)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: An answer that is all code without any description is nearly useless. The reader is forced to go line by line, character by character to see what you changed. This answer would be better if you added a paragraph or two explaining what the code does differently and why it works.

Comment: Thank @James Kent! you saved my day! and Bryan Oakly, he add description on the code

Comment: I used your code. And the problem is solved! Now I have another small problem with the size of the frame. When I make a list that is too large, I can not see the beginning of the list (for example in this code I start to see only from 500 number).

Comment: @BryanOakley my appologies, i should have added an explanatory paragraph, however i did add comments line by line where i made changes, including a brief "why"

Comment: @ShiraOzeri my mistake, in the call to `canvas.create_window` you can specify the anchor, in your case you would want to add `, anchor="n"` i've amended the code

Answer (score 1):

You can only scroll objects in a canvas if they are added to the canvas via the [`create_window`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_window.html) method, and not with `grid`, `pack`, or `place`.